# How to fix the ECONNREFUSED NodeJS( + NEST ) error when making fetch request in a dockerized node server?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nestjs, node-fetch

I am trying to make a fetch request using a dockerized NodeJS( + nest framework ) (version 16.20.0) server.
The docker image contains a strapi container running on http://localhost:1337/ and nodejs_api container running on http://localhost:4000/.

I am trying to make a GET request to strapi, but i am getting the following error:

```
[2] FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/login-page failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
```

So I created two servers (BOTH with the same code) to see what the problem is, one running in a dockerized container and one that is not dockerized.
The dockerized one seems to be the one with the error. The NOT dockerized one is fine and i can make requests that work.

I tried fetching (as you will see below in the globalLabels.service file) using  `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` BUT nothing seems to work.
Also tried rebuilding the docker image.

What could be the issue?

Here's the code for both the servers:
panel-content.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GetLabelsService } from '../get-labels/get-labels.service';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

//Get all the labels related to the admin-panel
@Controller('panel-content')
export class PanelContentController {
    constructor(private readonly getLabels: GetLabelsService){}

    @Get('ad-board-page')
    async getAdBoardLabels(){
        const labels = this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/ad-board-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('chats-page')
    async getChatsLabels(){
        const labels = this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/chats-page');
        return labels
    }
    
    @Get('collections-page')
    async getCollectionsLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/collections-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('events-page')
    async getEventsLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/events-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('home-page')
    async getHomepageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/home-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('login-page')
    async getLoginPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/login-page');
        
        return labels
    }

    @Get('news-page')
    async getNewsPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/news-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('notifications-page')
    async getNotificationsPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/notifications-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('orders-page')
    async getOrdersPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/orders-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('shop-page')
    async getShopPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/shop-page');
        return labels
    }

    @Get('users-page')
    async getUsersPageLabels(){
        const labels = await this.getLabels.getRouteLabels('/api/users-page');
        return labels
    }
}
```

getLabels.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

@Injectable()
export class GetLabelsService {
    async getRouteLabels(labelPath: string) {
        const request = `http://127.0.0.1:1337${labelPath}`;
        console.log(request)
        const res = await fetch(request);
        const labels_data = await res.json();
        delete labels_data.data.attributes.createdAt;
        delete labels_data.data.attributes.publishedAt;
        delete labels_data.data.attributes.updatedAt;
        delete labels_data.meta;
        return labels_data
    }
}
```

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mypta-backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"node index.js\" \"node socket.js\" \"nest start\"",
    "start:dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"node index.js\" \"node socket.js\" \"nest start --watch\"",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "migration:create": "typeorm migration:create -n",
    "migration:run": "NODE_ENV=dev&& ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "set NODE_ENV=dev&& ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:revert",
    "migration:generate": "set NODE_ENV=dev&& yarn typeorm migration:generate -n",
    "schema:sync": "yarn typeorm schema:sync",
    "schema:drop": "yarn typeorm schema:drop",
    "cache:clear": "yarn typeorm cache:clear",
    "seed:run": "set NODE_ENV=dev&& ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js seed",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.8.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.7",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.4.5",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.20",
    "@types/randomstring": "^1.1.8",
    "@types/validator": "^13.6.6",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "node-fetch": "2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "socket.io": "3.1.2",
    "stripe": "^8.191.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.40",
    "typeorm-seeding": "^1.6.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-api
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: ${DB_TYPE}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      APP_HOST: ${APP_HOST}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      JWT_EXIPRY_TIME: ${JWT_EXIPRY_TIME}
      STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY: ${STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY}
      STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: ${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}
      currency: ${currency}
      FCM_DATABASE_URL: ${FCM_DATABASE_URL}
      SMTP_HOST: ${SMTP_HOST}
      SMTP_USERNAME: ${SMTP_USERNAME}
      SMTP_PASSWORD: ${SMTP_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_container
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      PMA_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 64M
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  strapi:
    build:
      context: ./cms
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cms
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      APP_KEYS: ${APP_KEYS}
      API_TOKEN_SALT: ${API_TOKEN_SALT}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      MASTER_KEY: ${MASTER_KEY}
      MEILI_HOST: http://meilisearch:7700
      CLOUDINARY_KEY: ${CLOUDINARY_KEY}
      CLOUDINARY_NAME: ${CLOUDINARY_NAME}
      CLOUDINARY_SECRET: ${CLOUDINARY_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./cms/config:/srv/app/config
      - ./cms/src:/srv/app/src
      - ./cms/package.json:/srv/package.json
      - ./cms/yarn.lock:/srv/yarn.lock
      - ./cms/datadump:/srv/app/datadump
      - ./cms/public:/srv/app/public
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: yarn develop

  meilisearch:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:latest
    environment:
      MEILI_MASTER_KEY: ${MASTER_KEY}
    ports:
      - 7700:7700
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv/app/data
      
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  # Back-end services 
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db_data:
  pgdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

DockerFile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/api
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/api/

RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:dev" ]
```

as you can see, im using node-fetch to also make requests.

Comment: docker service inspect strapi.

Comment: @RichardRublev what do you mean?

Comment: show output docker service inspect strapi.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the Nest API from within a docker container (looks like you are via your docker-compose) you can use the compose service's name as the `host`, so instead of using `127.0.0.1` you can use `strapi` and docker should set up the DNS resolution to point to the strapi container's IP.

Comment: So it should be http://strapi:1337/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:1337 or http://localhost:1337/?

Comment: I actually got  the following error now ::: [Nest] 60  - 06/12/2023, 3:02:16 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported                                                                            i used strapi:1337/ as base URL